# How do I find group means of other values for split arrays?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby

So far I have grouped my data into 10 equal, sorted groups of stratified income.In the attrition dataset there are columns for 'MonthlyIncome' and 'JobSatisfaction'(rated 1-4 integer). I have found the mean for each group's income, and now want to find the mean Job Satisfaction for each of these groups to compare. What are some ways to accomplish this?

```
sorted_income= attrition['MonthlyIncome'].sort_values()
income_by_level= np.array_split(sorted_income, 10)
mean_income_by_level= list(map(lambda x: np.mean(x), income_by_level))` 
mean_income_by_level
```

Output

```
[1991.9591836734694,
 2489.6326530612246,
 2940.5646258503402,
 3794.904761904762,
 4562.102040816327,
 5317.476190476191,
 6337.340136054422,
 8373.925170068027,
 11521.979591836734,
 17699.428571428572]`
```

and I would love to see each corresponding Job Satisfaction mean.

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have an already sorted DataFrame.

In case you don't have a group column you can do the following to generate it (it is important that your frame is sorted before you do that to not mix up the groups):

```
df['group'] = (df.index / (df.shape[0]/10.)).astype(int)
```

Then perform the groupby

```
df.groupby('group').agg({'income':np.mean,'satisfaction':np.mean, 'abc':np.mean })
```

Comment: with  `attrition['MonthlyIncome'] = (attrition.index / (attrition.shape[0]/10.)).astype(int) `you are overwriting the MonthlyIncome column. Just do `attrition['groups'] = (attrition.index / (attrition.shape[0]/10.)).astype(int)` and `attrition.groupby('groups').agg({'MonthlyIncome':np.mean,'JobSatisfaction':np.mean})`